# Faye ruby client publishing only once

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine, faye

I have a faye server (nodejs) running on localhost, and I am trying to setup a server side ruby client which needs to publish on the server on a regular basis. This is the code I am trying to use.
(Please ignore the commented code to start with).
I make a class variable `@@client` and initialize it as soon as the class loads. I define a class method `pub` whose task is to publish something on the faye server.
In the end, I just call the `pub` method twice. The first publication callback is received successfully, but the second publication doesn't make either of `callback` or the `errback`. And since the control has not been given back to the app, the app just hangs there.
If I make the gobal variable `$client` (currently commented), the behaviour is the same. But if I make the client everytime `pub`  is called, then the publish goes on smoothly. I initiate it in `EM.run` loop or outside, the behavior is same. (as expected)

I don't want to make a new connection everytime I want to publish something since that defeats the purpose. Also, if I create a new client in `EM.run` everytime I call the method, the client connections don't close by themselves. I can see them open in `lsof` command as open files, and soon I'll start getting `too many open files` error I think.

I don't really understand Event Machine correctly, maybe I am missing something there.

```
require 'faye'
require 'eventmachine'

# $client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:5050/faye')
class Fayeclient
  puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s

  # if !defined? @@client or @@client.nil?
    @@client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:5050/faye')
    puts "Created client: " + @@client.inspect
  # end

  def self.pub
    puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s
    # client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:5050/faye') #$client
    # client = @@client
    EM.run {
      #client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:5050/faye') #$client
      puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s
      puts @@client.inspect

      publication = @@client.publish('/foo', 'text' =>'Hello world')
      puts "Publishing: #{publication.inspect}"
      # puts "Publication methods: #{publication.methods}"

      publication.callback do
        puts "Did it #{publication.inspect}"
        EM.stop_event_loop
        puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s
        # puts "#{client.methods}"
#        puts client.inspect
#        client.remove_all_listeners
#        puts client.inspect
      end
      publication.errback do |error |
          puts error.inspect
          EM.stop_event_loop
      end
    }
    puts "Outside event loop"
    puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s
  end
end

Fayeclient.pub
Fayeclient.pub
```

Comment: I can't help you with that specifically, but you might want to check out https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub. It's higher-level with secure channels, done entirely in Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EM.run` call is blocking, you have to run it on a separate thread, and eventually join it when all is over. In the example I'm using [Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) but it's up to you.

This does correctly the 2 faye calls.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
require 'faye'
require 'singleton'
require 'eventmachine'


class Fayeclient
  include Singleton
  attr_accessor :em_thread, :client

  def initialize
    self.em_thread = Thread.new do
      EM.run
    end
    self.client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:8890/faye')
  end

  def pub
    puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s
    puts client.inspect

    publication = client.publish('/foo', 'text' =>'Hello world')
    puts "Publishing: #{publication.inspect}"

    publication.callback do
      puts "Did it #{publication.inspect}"
      EM.stop_event_loop
      puts "#{__LINE__}: Reactor running: " + EM.reactor_running?.to_s
    end
    publication.errback do |error |
        puts error.inspect
        EM.stop_event_loop
    end
  end
end

Fayeclient.instance.pub
Fayeclient.instance.pub

Fayeclient.instance.em_thread.join
```

In my personal experience, anyway, having to deal with EventMachine inside Rails application can be a mess, some webserver uses EM, other does not so, and when you want to test from console it may not work as expected.

My solution is to fallback to http calls:

```
RestClient.post "http://localhost:#{Rails.configuration.faye_port}/faye", message: {foo: 'bar'}.to_json
```

I found this solution simpler and easy to customize, if you don't need to receive message from this piece of code.